# Read SharedPreference for flutter using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

What I want to do is read on the native side using Swift the data that I saved inside my flutter code.

I try:

```dart
// Dart code using SharedPreference package
(await _sharedPreferences).setString('lastUser', userId);
```

```swift
// Native code on swift using UserDefaults
let userId: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "flutter.lastUser") ?? ""
let userIdFlutter: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastUser") ?? ""
```

In both cases an empty string is return.

**Update:**

It have something to do with the extensions and groups because on the main part of the app (example: `com.name.name_app`) I can find the store value.

But on the extension (example: `com.name.name_app.Extension`) I can't find it even passing the suitName of the main section (`com.name.name_app`)

Example:

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift
let userId: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "flutter.lastUser")
// userId is found
```

```swift
// OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.swift
let userDefaults = USerDefaults(suitName: "com.name.name_app") {
  let userId: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "flutter.lastUser")
  // userId is not found
}
```